# Sub domain issue - IIS 8

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-8, cfwheels

I have a CF Wheels Application under test.example.com and is working as it should and I am trying to add another mapping to it through IIS but I am running into an issue. The new sub domain is new.example.com and is rerouting to an IIS 8 landing page instead of the app. When I call the new mapping like this new.example.com/index.cfm/controller/view is working as it should.

Anyone ran into this before to help out a bit?

Comment: Without your sharing some details about how you have IIS configured, I'm afraid that no one will be able to help you.

Comment: @ChrisPeters what details do you need exactly so I can post them?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have setup another host in IIS?
2. What are your Settings in web.xml?

Maybe tomorrow I can have a look in my setup. But it's for IIS 7.5 but should be comparable.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the default document for the site and/or delete the default document that IIS generated when the site was created.